# Does every finite dimensional real nil algebra admit a multiplicative basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We say that a finite dimensional real commutative and associative algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is nil if every element $a \in \mathcal{A}$ is nilpotent.

By multiplicative basis, I mean a basis $\{ v_1, \dots , v_n \}$ for $\mathcal{A}$ as a real vector space such that for each $v_i$ and $v_j$, the algebra multiplication $v_i \star v_j = c v_k$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and some other element $v_k$ of the basis.

Given such a nil algebra $\mathcal{A}$, does it always admit a multiplicative basis in the sense described above? If not, what is an example of a nil algebra which does not admit a multiplicative basis?

Comment: It seems to me that you can describe this as a twisted semigroup ring over a torsion group.

Comment: An algebra with multiplicative basis? I think that sounds reasonable based on what I know about twisted group rings, though I haven't heard of twisted semigroup rings before, I'd imagine the concept is analogous.

Comment: Hrm, I guess torsion doesn't quite make sense for semigroups... it should probably be a different word, where you have a semigroup with zero element, and every element has some power equal to the zero element

Comment: I looked around at likely candidates and I did find them called "nil semigroups," so I'd revise my original comment to be "twisted semigroup ring over a nil semigroup."

Comment: Is $\mathcal{A}$ supposed to be unital?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook That complicates the question, as what I've been calling a "unital nil algebra" I don't think is common terminology, but we can always use the standard construction taking a non-unital ring to a ring with unity, and I don't think the presence of a 1 has no real bearing on the question of the existence of a multiplicative basis.

Comment: Am I missing something or is this actually easy? e.g. let $A = \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. The algebra $(x,y)A / (x,y)^3 A$ has five basis elements $x,y,x^2,xy,y^2$. To make a counterexample we just impose the further relation that $y^2 = x^2 + xy$. i.e. $(x,y)A / ((x,y)^3 A + (y^2-x^2) A)$

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't know. Just because the standard basis isn't multiplicative doesn't mean the algebra doesn't admit some multiplicative basis. I have a few examples where I've tried to construct such a thing using similar methods to what you did there, but never came up with an example where the algebra did not admit a multiplicative basis.

Comment: @Hurkyl In your example, let $v_1=2x+(1+\sqrt{5})y$ and $v_2=-(1+\sqrt{5})x+2y$. Then $v_1v_2=0$, so $(v_1,v_2,v_1^2,v_2^2)$ is a multiplicative basis.

Comment: @Hurkyl I initially thought your counterexample could be salvaged by replacing $y^2=x^2+xy$ with $x^2+y^2=0$, but this is not the case : in that situation $(x,y,x^2,xy)$ is a multiplicative basis.

Comment: @Sintrastes: That's why I asked! Having examples where the 'obvious' thing fails is very helpful.

Comment: In fact, it was @EwanDelanoy 's examples that clued me into what's going on, and thus what I needed to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The following constructs a counterexample.

Let $R$ be the graded ring $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_5]$ and $I = (x_1, \ldots, x_5)$. In any homgeneous degree $d$, define the "pure" polynomials to be the the products of $d$ linear polynomials, and let the rank of a homogeneous polynomial $f$ be the minimum number of terms needed to express $f$ as a sum of pure polynomials.

I assert the following:

- The grade one piece $R_1$ is isomorphic to the vector space of $1 \times 5$ matrices
- The grade two piece $R_2$ is isomorphic to the vector space of symmetric $5 \times 5$ matrices
- The product $R_1 \times R_1 \to R_2$  corresponds to the symmetrized outer product $(v,w) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v^Tw + w^Tv)$

(phrased differently: $R_1$ is the space of linear forms, and $R_2$ is the space of symmetric bilinear forms)

The rank of a matrix has a similar characterization: $\text{rank}(A)$ is the smallest number of terms you need to express $A$ as a sum of outer products $\sum_i v_i^T w_i$.

Of particular note is that if a homogeneous quadratic polynomial $f$ corresponds to the matrix $A$, then $\text{rank}(A) \leq 2 \text{rank}(f)$.

Consequently, there exists a homogeneous quadratic polynomial $f$ such that $\text{rank}(f) \geq 3$. One such example is $f = \sum_i x_i^2$.

Now, consider the graded algebra $A = I / (I^3 + fR)$. Its grade 1 piece is 5-dimensional and its grade 2 piece is 14-dimensional.

Suppose we have a collection of polynomials of $I$ that form a multiplicative basis for $A$. The basis must consist of at least five polynomials that span $I/I^2$. There are 15 products of pairs of these polynomials, and they are all distinct elements of $I^2 / I^3$.

Suppose two of these products were the same in $A$. That would imply we have two *rank one* quadratic polynomials $g$ and $h$ with the property that $rg = sh + tf$ for some scalars $r,s,t$. However, we would have $rt^{-1}g + (-st^{-1})h = f$ which is impossible, because the left hand side has rank at most 2, but the right hand side has rank 3.

Consequently, the 15 pairwise products of the multiplicative basis for $A$ are all distinct (and nonzero) elements of $A$, and they are distinct from the original $5$ polynomials as well. Consequently, the basis must have at least 20 elements, contradicting the fact that $A$ is 19-dimensional.

Comment: can I ask a possibly dumb question, why is this example a nil-algebra? (even if it isn't, it is still interesting as examples of algebras which do not permit multiplicative bases are apparently not so easy to find...). I'm also curious, what criteria will indicate the existence of a multiplicative basis... there must be some special sort of algebras which do permit such. In any event, thank you very much for this.

Comment: @James: Every element of $A$ is the class of some element of $I$. Thus, every product of $n$ elements is the class of some element of $I^n$. By construction, everything from $I^n \subseteq I^3$ is in the class of zero.